# Why does Django's render() function need the "request" argument?

Tags: django

Sorry for what might be a silly question, but why is the `request` argument mandatory in the `render()` function?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render) shortcut renders templates with a [request context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext). Template context processors take the request object and return a dictionary which is added to the context.

A common template context processor is the [auth context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth), which takes the request object, and adds the logged-in user to the context.

If you don't need to `render` the template with a request context, you can use `request=None`.

```
def my_view(request):
    return render(None, "my_template.html", {'foo': 'bar'})
```

Comment: Oh, I see, so render() is just a shortcut for render_to_response with context_instance=RequestContext(request). Thanks

Comment: Yes, but using `render_to_response` is [discouraged by the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response), so I would always recommend using `render`.

Answer (score 3):

For rendering a template outside of the context of a view (i.e. without a `request` object), one can use [`render_to_string()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string):

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

render_to_string('path/to/template.html', context={'key': 'val'})
```

Answer (score 0):

In django render is used for loading the templates.So for this we

```
import-from django.shortcuts import render
```

its a template shortcut. 
Rendering is the process of gathering data (if any) and load the associated templates

Comment: congrats on your first SO answer! Please consider adding more examples and expand your answer. Looks like it doesn't directly answer the question about the `requests` argument.